# Custom classes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having difficulties to add a custom class to my app.

It's a class that spiders a website and returns the results.

What i've found out is that I need to put it in the lib folder, I already pointed the autoload paths to the lib folder.. This is where I put it:

```
# /lib/booking_spider.rb

class BookingSpider

  def cities( city )

    return @cities

  end

end
```

This is how I call it in my controller:

```
p BookingSpider.cities( params[:search][:city] )
```

This error keeps popping up:

```
undefined method `cities' for BookingSpider:Class
```

Can someone tell me what I'm missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are trying to use the method as a class method, but it is defined as an instance method. Change to this:

```
class BookingSpider
  def self.cities(city)
    return @cities
  end
end
```

Here is some reading on the differences between class and instance methods: [method types in Ruby](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/)